# Open Popup with Javascript when the user types a word and presses enter?

Tags: javascript, popup, cpu-word

i have no idea how to write this javascript, maybe you can help me. I want to have a code which opens an Popup as soon as the user writes, for example, secret and presses enter any where on the site. So only this word with the combination of enter can open the popup. Is there anyway how this could work?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really coming forward

Comment: Where user should enter that word ? Is there some input field ?

Comment: Somewhere on the site, this should be like an easteregg. :D

Comment: Can you provide some code of your problem? @Sigron

Comment: Somewhere means that it can be different place and there is no special input field for that ?

Comment: Here's an example...type on this page somewhere the word SEARCH and press enter http://store.steampowered.com/app/253750

Answer (score 0):

i've made a working copy
please check http://goo.gl/1iMTH2